# Concerning API's canvas width

Tags: tabs, width, facebook-apps

I have a little problem with my API :

when I access to it with the link : http://apps.facebook.com/325997004142754/ the page is correctly displayed (good width) as you can see.

I added this API in my page's tabs (my company's page) and when I access to it with this tab (url = http://www.facebook.com/jmj.automobiles/app_325997004142754) page's display is now wrong (bad width)...

How to have the same page's width ?
What's the difference between those 2 API's url ?

PS : My company's page : www.facebook.com/jmj.automobiles

Thanks a lot !

Romain.

Answer (score 1):

Check your app isn't built using static CSS and/or you're not using the same Canvas callback that you're using as the Page Tab URL, because they're different sizes and if your code isn't expecting that it'll look weird.

- Page tab Apps have an iFrame width of Narrow (520px) or Wide (810px)
- Canvas apps have an iFrame width of Fixed (760px) or Fluid (extends to the width of the user's browser)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to resize?

[FB.Canvas.setSize](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/):

> Call this whenever you need a resize. This usually means, once after pageload, and whenever your content size changes.

```
// should be called when you know that your app's size changed
FB.Canvas.setSize();
```

[FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/)

> This function is useful if you know your content will change size, but you don't know when. There will be a slight delay, so if you know when your content changes size, you should call setSize yourself (and save your user's CPU cycles).

```
// should be called when you can't predict size changes
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
```

Comment: setSize is deprecated, the function has been renamed FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

Comment: Actually it is not deprecated, the docs state it should be used if you know you have to change size. There just is an automatic way of resizing available as a convenience. However, since it seems to use polling you might take a performance hit using it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake – FB.Canvas.setAutoResize has been deprecated, in favor of the new name FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow.